# smooth animation of the size of a functional component during state change

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

As you can see, by clicking on the component underneath, we can change its size. I would like to make a transition between those sizes. Is it possible with CSSTransition ?

```
export const Liste_planete2 = () => {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState<number>(30)

    const handleClick=()=>{
            setHeight(height+30)
    }
    return(
        <div style={{height:height}} onClick={handleClick}>
            Text
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
export const Liste_planete2 = () => {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState<number>(30)

    const handleClick=()=>{
            setHeight(height+30)
    }
    return(
        <div style={{height:height, transition: "all 0.5s"}} onClick={handleClick}>
            Text
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It's not valid JSX `{{height:height, transition: all 0.5s}}`

Comment: solved, try now

Comment: now it will work

Comment: Perfect Thank you